# Stuck with physics tensile strength problem

Tags: stress-energy-momentum-tensor, stress-strain

So this was a question in my exam.

I am not asking for the solution rather some help at a step.

> A glass spherical shell of radius $R$ has a point source of monochromatic light of wavelength $\lambda$. Thickness of glass wall is $t\space(t<<R)$. The inner surface is painted black so that it absoerbs all the adiation incident on it. The maximum power of the source such that the sphere does not rupture due to radian pressure is $P=(x)(2\pi\sigma^aR^bt^dc^e)$. Where $\sigma=$ tensile strength of glass, $c=$ speed of light. Then the value of $(x+a+b+d+e)$ is

So I started out by writing radiation pressure as $\frac{P}{4\pi R^2c}$. Now if I consider an elemental area $dA$ and write the eqution as $$\frac{P}{4\pi R^2c}.dA=\sigma.dA$$ which gives $$P=\sigma 4\pi R^2c$$

But the answer is 8.

I think that the tensile strength $\sigma=\frac{Force}{Area}$ has some different area in consideration which will include a factor of thickness $t$.

Comment: I would consider the thin spherical shell to consist of two thin hemispheres. You can then figure out the force pushing the two hemispheres apart due to radiant pressure. Also, you can work out the cross-sectional area of material associated with cutting a thin sphere into two thin hemispheres, so you should be able to figure out the required strength of the material from $\sigma$=F/A. That should give you the equation you need to relate all of the parameters to each other.